# styles.css has no affect on my JSF data table

Tags: html, css, jsf, netbeans

My `styles.css`file is as follows:

```
.akademisyenTable{   
border-collapse:collapse;
border:1px solid #000000;
}

.akademisyenTableHeader{
text-align:center;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #B5B5B5;
border-bottom:1px solid #000000;  
padding:2px;
}

.akademisyenTableOddRow{
text-align:center;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFFF; 
}

.akademisyenTableEvenRow{
text-align:center;
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #D3D3D3;
}
```

However, it has no affect on my data table. When I run this code I see a basic table view. I cannot find the problem. It gives no error. My index.xhtml is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="inputForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:inputFile id="file" 
                     label="file" 
                     value="#{InputBean.part}" 
                     required="true" 
                     requiredMessage="Dosya Seçilmeli">
            <f:validator validatorId="FileUploadValidator"/>
        </h:inputFile>
        <h:message style="color: red" for="file"/><br/>
        <h:commandButton id="submit" 
                         action="#{InputBean.uploadFile()}"
                         value="Upload File"/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{InputBean.statusMessage}"
                      rendered="#{not empty InputBean.statusMessage}"/><br/><br/>

    </h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{InputBean.akademisyenler}" var="akademisyen"
                 border="1"
                 rendered="#{not empty InputBean.akademisyenler}"
                 styleClass="akademisyenTable"
                 headerClass="akademisyenTableHeader"
                 rowClasses="akademisyenTableOddRow,akademisyenTableEvenRow">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
                #{akademisyen.idno}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Adı</f:facet>
                #{akademisyen.adi}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Soyadı</f:facet>
                #{akademisyen.soyadi}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Kullanıcı Adı</f:facet>
                #{akademisyen.kullaniciadi}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Şifre</f:facet>
                #{akademisyen.sifre}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Alan No</f:facet>
                #{akademisyen.ilgi}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Görev Alır</f:facet>
                #{akademisyen.gorevalir}
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I need help. Thanks.

I also noticed that there is a warning in Tomcat logs: `WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, styles.css`. I am using NetBeans. What is the correct place to put a resource file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure its linked to the correct directory of where your css file is located?

Comment: Yes of course. Otherwise browser would give "cannot find" error.

Comment: Sorry. Tomcat gives an warning. I did not check the logs. I am using NetBeans where should I put css files?

Comment: Thank you. I should have created a resource folder under Web pages directory and put the css file in it.